# Which prepositions to use for shops?

Tags: usage, preposition

How to say these sentence in German.
*I’m using example of Rossmann for the name of shop. Does the translation changes with name of shop?*

**I’m in Rossmann.** Ich bin bei Rossmann. (Wo)

**I buy it from Rossmann.** Ich kaufe es bei Rossmann. (Bei/von wem)

**I’m going to Rossmann.**  Ich gehe zu Rossmann. (Wohin)

**I’m coming from Rossmann.** Ich komme von Rossmann.(Woher)

Comment: Fragt ein Ruhrpottler einen Türken: "Wo geht's denn hier nach Aldi?" Sagt der Türke: "Zu Aldi!" Fragt der Ruhrpöttler: "Wie, haben wir schon Acht?"

Comment: Related (in German): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29183/ich-bin-in-der-beck-oder-in-dem-beck-wenn-der-beck-ein-laden-ist

Answer (score 4):

I’ll use different names of shops with different grammatical genders:

- Der **Baumarkt** is male.
- Die **Buchhandlung** is female.
- Das **Schuhgeschäft** ist neuter.
- **Rossmann** is male, but since it is a person’s name you normally don’t use an article for it. But in case of a shop it is often unclear, if the name refers to the shop itself (which is not a person) or to it’s owner or fonder (who is a person). So in case of shop-names you are often free about the usage of articles.

If you are inside a shop you use »*in*« (+ article if it is not named after a person) (remember: preposition »*in*« + article »*dem*« = preposition with included article »*im*«):

> Ich bin **im** Baumarkt.
>   Ich bin **in der** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich bin **im** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich bin **im** Rossmann. (here you use the hidden article *dem* because it is clear that the thing where you are inside is not a person, but a shop)
>   <sub>wrong: <del>Ich bin **in** Rossmann.</del> (»in« without article would mean, that you are inside a person, not inside a shop)</sub>

If you are not inside, but close to a shop you use »*bei*« + article (remember: bei + dem = beim):

> Ich bin **beim** Baumarkt.
>   Ich bin **bei der** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich bin **beim** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich bin **bei** Rossmann. (you can omit the article here)
>   Ich bin **beim** Rossmann. (but it is allowed)

But you can use *bei* also if you are inside the shop. This is correct too and very common.

If you buy something **at** a shop (a shop is not a person), you also use *bei* or *in*. But if you buy it **from** someone (i.e. a person), you say *von*:

> Ich kaufe es **beim** Baumarkt.
>   Ich kaufe es **bei der** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich kaufe es **beim** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich kaufe es **bei/beim** Rossmann.
>
> Ich kaufe es **im** Baumarkt.
>   Ich kaufe es **in der** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich kaufe es **im** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich kaufe es **im** Rossmann. (not »*in*«!)
>
> Ich kaufe es **von** Herrn Meier. (Herr Meier is masculine)
>   Ich kaufe es **von** Frau Müller. (Frau Müller is feminine)
>   Ich kaufe es **von dem** Mädchen. (Das Mädchen is neuter; since »Mädchen« is not a name you need an article)

If you are going to a shop, you use *zu* + Article (zu + dem = zum; zu + der = zur):

> Ich gehe **zum** Baumarkt.
>   Ich gehe **zur** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich gehe **zum** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich gehe **zu** Rossmann. (No Articles for names)
>   Ich gehe **zum** Rossmann. (But Articles can also be used in this case)

If you are coming from a shop, you use *von* + Article (von + dem = vom):

> Ich komme **vom** Baumarkt.
>   Ich komme **von der** Buchhandlung.
>   Ich komme **vom** Schuhgeschäft.
>   Ich komme **von** Rossmann. (no Article)
>   Ich komme **vom** Rossmann. (with Article)

Comment: ‘So in case of shop-names you are often free about the usage of articles.’ How true: Examples: *Edeka* usually takes masculine/neuter (indistinguishable to me atm), even though it ends in *a* and stands for a *Einkaufsgenossenschaft* (feminine). *Norma,* on the other hand, allows both *im Norma* and *in der Norma*.

Comment: @Jan: In Österreich gibt es eine Buchhandelskette die nach der Muse der komischen Dichtkunst benannt ist: Thalia. Und obwohl Thalia eindeutig weiblich ist, hat das Buchgeschäft einen männlichen Artikel: Der Thalia (»Ich gehe zum Thalia«). Die Marketingabteilung von Thalia vermeidet es selbst tunlichst, einen Artikel zu verwenden (Aus der Werbung: »Wie findest du das?« - »*Bei* Thalia«)

Comment: @Jan: Ich gehe zu Edeka, weder zum Edeka, noch zur Edeka.

Comment: Und ich gehe auch **zu** Thalia. Gibt es wirklich Leute, die **zum** Thalia gehen?

Comment: @Iris: Ja, meine Frau beispielsweise.

Comment: @Iris: Ja. Zum Lidl, zum Aldi, zum Rewe, zum Edeka, zum Thalia. Ist hier im Südwesten im gesprochenen Deutsch sehr verbreitet. Wobei auch hier manche Leute tatsächlich zur Thalia (aber vermutlich dennoch zum Edeka) gehen würden, aber eher nicht zu Thalia.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of discussing the details, here is how it all makes sense and is hard to forget:

1. If the word you use to refer to a shop is an established word for some physical thing or ends in one (Laden, Geschäft, …handlung, Markt), then normally the prepositions are selected based on what makes sense for a house (even in the case of *Markt*, which on its own gets different prepositions suitable for a market square), and the gender according to that word.
2. Otherwise, the prepositions (and lack of definite article) are based on the fiction or reality that the shop’s name is the name of the founder/owner and the fiction that you are visiting the founder/owner for tea or a chat and then buy some things on the side while you are there.

There are no clear rules for selecting between the two metaphors. 2 is so common that it can almost be considered the regular case. It is certainly often generalised to typical 1 cases. On the other hand, when the context is rather concrete and physical, 1 is often used instead of 2.

Some corollaries:

- Using the definite article is normal in case 1. It is colloquial if not vulgar (depending on the region) w.r.t. persons, and so the same applies to shops in case 2.
- You are and buy 1. *in*, 2. *bei* the shop.
- You go 1. *in/zu*, 2. *zu* the shop.
- You come 1. *aus/von* 2. *von* the shop.

Answer (score 0):

My answers below might not be grammatically correct and they might not be “correct” with respect to the dialect spoken in different parts of Germany.

> I’m in Rossmann.

*Ich bin gerade beim Rossmann/Aldi* or *Ich bin im Rossmann*

> I buy it from Rossmann.

*Ich kaufe es bei Rossmann/Aldi* but *Ich kaufe es im Aldi* (for some reason »Ich kaufe es im Rossmann« sounds strange to me)

> I’m going to Rossmann.

*Ich gehe zu(m) Rossmann* you might also hear *Ich gehe bei Rossmann/Aldi* but I would not recommend that.

> I’m coming from Rossmann.

*Ich komme vom Rossmann* but *Ich komme von Ikea*

I am not sure if this answers your question actually because when I think about it, it seems one has to learn it for every shop there is, because for certain shops we speak of as if it would be the butcher or baker.