# Ich bin in der Beck oder in dem Beck (wenn "der Beck" ein Laden ist)

Tags: grammar

Es gibt eine Bäckerei, die "der Beck" heißt.
Der "der" Artikel gehört zu dem Namen.
[image: Der Beck Logo]

Wie sagt man richtig:

1. Ich bin in "der Beck"
2. Ich bin in dem Beck
3. Ich gehe zu "der Beck"
4. Ich gehe zu dem Beck

Comment: "Beck" heisst in vielen Mundarten einfach "Bäcker" - Ich weiss nicht, ob das in deiner Gegend der Fall ist, aber dann hiesse es "Ich bin beim Beck"

Comment: Related: [Which prepositions to use for shops?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25751/9551)

Comment: Der Artikel mag zur Wortmarke gehören, aber man kauft die neue Platte der Beatles, nicht der Die Beatles. Da der falsche Sprachgebrauch nicht strafbewehrt ist laufen immer noch viele Werbetexter frei umher. :seufz:

Comment: In Graz (meiner Geburtsstadt) gab es bis 2015 einen Bäcker, der hieß »Kotzbeck« http://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ybJ7VV0JHiXNLJaejUmLkQ/o.jpg und http://www.kleinezeitung.at/images/uploads/2/0/4/4211204/waltendorf1611leodolter726.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Präpositionen für Orte, in denen man einkaufen kann, sind uneinheitlich. Alle folgenden Beispiele können je nach Region richtig sein, aber Präpositionen können selbst innerhalb einer Region schwanken.

> - Ich gehe **auf** den Markt.
> - Ich gehe **in** das Einkaufszentrum.
> - Ich gehe **zum** Bäcker.

Das ist leider auch bei Läden, deren Namen bekannt sind, noch so:

> - Ich gehe **in** den Saturn.
> - Ich gehe **zu** Ikea.
> - Ich gehe **zu(m)** MediaMarkt.

Wenn der Eigennamen des Händlers gemeint ist, findet man die Präposition **bei**.

> - Ich kaufe meine Brötchen **beim** Beck.

Als Faustregel ist die Präposition **auf** für Märkte und andere Plätze unter freiem Himmel, die Präposition **in** für größere Gebäude mit mehreren Läden oder für Einkaufsstraßen und die Präposition **zu** (mit oder ohne Artikel) für einen einzelnen Laden gebräuchlich.

Wenn der Artikel Bestandteil des Namens ist, wird er [kleingeschrieben und dekliniert](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Eigennamen.html?lang=de), bzw. in die Verkürzung *zum* integriert.

Man würde also im genannten Beispiel wie folgt sagen:

> Ich gehe **zum** Beck.

Mit der Präposition **in** wird im genannten Beispiel tatsächlich der Ort der Bäckerei gemeint:

> *Ich lege meine Werbeprospekte **im** Beck aus. **Im** Beck ist es immer voll. Ich bin gerade **im** Beck.*

Comment: In Österreich: Ich gehe *zum* Saturn, *zum* Ikea und *zum* MediaMarkt. Sogar: Ich gehe *zum* Thalia, obwohl die Muse »Thalia« eindeutig weiblich ist. Aber das Büchergeschäft »Thalia« wird meist als männlich empfunden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ganz richtig, es gibt eine gehörige Variation, nicht nur regional sondern auch innerhalb einer Region. Das zeigt allemal, wie uneinheitlich die Präpositionen sind. Obige Beispiele sollen nur das verdeutlichen und nicht eine "korrekte" Variante geben. Ich editiere das mal, Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das würde ich für Baden-Würrtemberg genauso bestätigen.

Comment: @Takkat, deine Antwort ist zwar ausreichend, aber das, was mich eben interessiert hat, und worüber gefragt ist, steht ganz am Ende.